# extracting the second last word between the special characters "/"

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

I would like to extract the second last string after the '/' symbol. For example,

```
url<- c('https://example.com/names/ani/digitalcod-org','https://example.com/names/bmc/ambulancecod.org' )
df<- data.frame (url)
```

I want to extract the second word from the last between the two // and would like to get the words 'ani' and 'bmc'

so, I tried this

```
 library(stringr)
 df$name<- word(df$url,-2)
```

I need output which as follows:

```
name 
ani
bmc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `word` but you need to specify the separator,

```
library(stringr)

word(url, -2, sep = '/')
#[1] "ani" "bmc"
```

Comment: There should be more efficient ways. I was just continuing your train of thought

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(str_extract_all(df$url,"\\w{2,}(?=\\/)"),"["))[3,]
#   V1  V2
#3 ani bmc
  as.data.frame(sapply(str_extract_all(df$url,"\\w{2,}(?=\\/)"),"["))[2:3,]
#   V1    V2
#2 names names
#3   ani   bmc
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex approach using `basename`

```
basename(mapply(sub, pattern = basename(url), replacement = "", x = url, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] "ani" "bmc"
```

`basename(url)` "removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator (if any)" and returns

```
[1] "digitalcod-org"   "ambulancecod.org"
```

use `mapply` to replace this outcome for every element in `url` by `""` and call `basename` again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` with

```
.*?([^/]+)/[^/]+$
```

---

In `R`:

```
urls <- c('https://example.com/names/ani/digitalcod-org','https://example.com/names/bmc/ambulancecod.org' )
gsub(".*?([^/]+)/[^/]+$", "\\1", urls)
```

This yields

```
[1] "ani" "bmc"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ic4SYt/2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `strsplit`

```
words <- strsplit(url, '/')
L <- lengths(words)
vapply(seq_along(words), function (k) words[[k]][L[k]-1], character(1))    
# [1] "ani" "bmc"
```